# Hide parent UL using jQuery at the same time show the nested child UL which was previously hidden with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a `<ul>` list that is nested inside of a parent `<ul>` the child is hidden, i want to show it when a link is clicked in its parent. At the same time i want the parent `<ul>` content to be hidden (without hiding the child).

I know i could work around this by having two separate `<ul>` lists that were un nested but Ive been trying to keep them nested following the W3 guidelines on nested lists.

The issue Im having at the moment is that when the main list is hidden it also hides the child and does not allow it to be shown.

Ive made a jsfiddle of the issue here - http://jsfiddle.net/xc0g770z/

The HTML Im using is

```
<ul id="main-list">
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>TWO</li>
    <li>THREE</li>
    <li>FOUR</li>
    <li>FIVE</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="open-submenu">SIX</a>
        <ul id="sub-nav">
            <li>SIX - ONE</li>
            <li>SIX - TWO</li>
            <li>SIX - THREE</li>
            <li>SIX - FOUR</li>
            <li>RETRUN</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>SEVEN</li>
    <li>EIGHT</li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery Im using is

```
$("#open-submenu").click(function () {
     $("#main-list").hide();
     $("#sub-nav").show();
});
```

Any ideas how i could get this to work whilst still using the nested  ?

Comment: Try '#main-list>li' as the "parent" selector and '$(this).parent()' as the "curently opened" selector.

Comment: The parent is a wrapper, anything in that will be hidden when the parent is hidden. If you want one or the other you'll need separate lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/murid/xc0g770z/1/

```
$("#sub-nav").hide();
$("#open-submenu a").click(function () {
     $("#main-list li").hide();
     $("#open-submenu").show();
     $("#sub-nav").show();
     $("#sub-nav li").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use class

```
<ul>
<li class="main-list">ONE</li>
<li class="main-list">TWO</li>
<li class="main-list">THREE</li>
<li class="main-list">FOUR</li>
<li class="main-list">FIVE</li>
<li class="main-list" id="open-submenu">SIX<li></a>
<li class="six-sub">SIX - ONE</li>
<li class="six-sub">SIX - TWO</li>
<li class="six-sub">SIX - THREE</li>
<li class="six-sub">SIX - FOUR</li>
<li class="six-sub">RETRUN</li>
<li class="main-list">SEVEN</li>
<li class="main-list">EIGHT</li>
</ul>
```

The in the jquery

```
$("#open-submenu").click(function () {
 $(".main-list").hide();
 $(".six-sub").show();  
});
```